# Row_number over (Partition by yyy) in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, window-functions

I want to load data by Row_number over Partition by using EF.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (
       SELECT sf.SerialFlowsId
                     ,sf.GoodsSerialId
                     ,d.FormTypeId
                     , d.GoodsId
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.GoodsId, sf.GoodsSerialId ORDER BY sf.Date DESC)row
       FROM sam.SerialFlows sf
       INNER JOIN sam.Detail d ON d.DetailId = sf.DetailId
       )z
WHERE z.row =1 
       AND z.FormTypeId=7
       AND z.GoodsId=51532
```

this query is my expectance.

I try to use this expression but unfortunately Zip extension method not recognize in ef

```
var goodsSerials = context.SerialFlows.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).GroupBy(x => new { x.Detail.GoodsID, x.Date })
                    .Select(g => new {g})
                    .SelectMany(z => z.g.Select(c => c)).Zip(m, (j, i) => new { GoodSerial=j,j.Detail.FormTypeID,j.Detail.GoodsID,rn=i })
                    .Where(x => x.rn== 1 && x.GoodsID== goodsId && x.FormTypeID==7).Select(x => x.GoodSerial).ToList();
```

I have more than 20000000 records in SerialFlows table.

**Edited

```
  var goodsSerials = context.SerialFlows
                                          .Where(e => e.Detail.GoodsID == goodsId )
                                          .GroupBy(x => x.GoodsSerialID)
                                          .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Date).Take(1))
                                          .SelectMany(e => e.Where(x=>x.Detail.FormTypeID==7).Select(z=>z.GoodsSerial)).ToList();
```

*** Solved by this Query

```
        var goodsSerials = context.SerialFlows
                                          .Include(x => x.Detail)
                                          .Where(e => e.Detail.GoodsID == goodsId)
                                          .GroupBy(x => x.GoodsSerialID)
                                          .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Date).Take(1).Where(x=>x.Detail.FormTypeID==7))
                                          .SelectMany(e => e.Select(z => z.GoodsSerial)).ToList();
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Seems like a perfectly good question to me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From your SQL query, I think you need to first group them all by what in `PARTITION BY` clause, order each group by Date. Then project each group to include each entry with its index. Then `SelectMany` to flatten all groups, then apply filter and finally project the result you want. You can see that we don't need the so-called `Zip` at all.

***Edit***: because you need to filter on row number but looks like the `Select` method accepting an `Expression<Func<T,int,TResult>>` is not supported (as well as the `Zip` method in Linq To Entity). I don't think it's the problem of building the Expression tree, meaning even building it manually, it still won't be supported. I think you can use some work-around in which you can still filter the row you want using `Skip` and `Take` instead.

The following code will filter just the first row in each group (equivalent to the condition `rn == 1`):

```
var goodsSerials = context.SerialFlows
                          .Where(e => e.Detail.GoodsID == goodsId &&
                                      e.Detail.FormTypeID == 7)
                          .GroupBy(x => new { x.Detail.GoodsID, x.GoodsSerialId })
                          .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Date)
                                        .Take(1))
                          .SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
```

The `Where` filters for just 1 value of `GoodsID` so the `GroupBy` does not need to include the `GoodsID` into the key, so it would be simpler like this:

```
var goodsSerials = context.SerialFlows
                          .Where(e => e.Detail.GoodsID == goodsId &&
                                      e.Detail.FormTypeID == 7)
                          .GroupBy(x => x.GoodsSerialId)
                          .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Date).Take(1))
                          .SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
```

I hope you understand the idea of using `Skip` and `Take` to apply in various cases.

Comment: unforunently i've got error.Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Comment: @MahdiFarhani see my edit, looks like we hardly can extract the row number, but for the purpose of filtering, we have a pretty work-around.

Comment: it's run,but the performance is not acceptable.it's take over 4 minutes and i've canceled it.

Comment: i run the SQL query generated by EF in sql server,it's took 14 min and the result was empty.

Comment: @MahdiFarhani I was blinded from your original query, I think it can be done much more simply, try the edited code.

Comment: i've changed the query (Post Edited) and it's work but it's took 34 sec.when i run the sql query with over partition sql server response immediately

Comment: @MahdiFarhani that's not my query, Why don't you use my query? The `Where` should be placed first.

Comment: dear King King it's work good and I solve the performance issue.

Comment: I changed where cluse becuase it show wrong data, also the performance issue is related to TPT inheritance in EF.

Comment: @MahdiFarhani I'm glad to know that. Ah maybe there is some business logic involved here (that I was not aware of).