# LINQ Expression GroupBy Select First

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I've got a question on LINQ Expression. I need to replicate the following lambda:

```
var result = processRevisions
   OrderByDescending(pr => pr.CreatedAt)
   GroupBy(pr => pr.IdProcess)
   Select(pr => pr.First());
```

which result is the latest revision created for every process, in LINQ expression.

I start with this code:

```
Expression<Func<ProcessRevision, DateTime>> orderProcessRevision = f => f.CreatedAt;
Expression<Func<ProcessRevision, long>> groupProcessRevision = f => f.IdProcess;
Expression<Func<ProcessRevision, ProcessRevision>> selectProcessRevision = f => f;

processRevisions = await processRevisionRepository.GetDatasByLastRevisionAsync(orderProcessRevision, groupProcessRevision, selectProcessRevision);
```

The repository is as follows:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetDatasByLastRevisionAsync(
   Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> order,
   Expression<Func<T, long>> group,
   Expression<Func<T, T>> select)
{
   IQueryable<T> query = dbContext.Set<T>();

   query = query.OrderByDescending(order);
   query = query.GroupBy(group);
   query = query.Select(select);

   return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

The only part of the query which works is the `orderbydescending`. Then, the `groupby` yields an error (implicit convert `IGrouping` to `IQueryable`) and also the select first item of each group goes in error.

How to apply the `groupby` (`igrouping`) to `IQueryable` and for every group take the first object?

Thanks for help.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098361/row-number-over-partition-by-yyy-in-entity-framework

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the error is because the result of `.GroupBy` is not `IQueryable<T>` so you can't assign it to `query`. Maybe you could assign it to a new variable? (not sure if that works, have no environment to test it for you)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that GroupBy doesn't return an `IQueryable<T>` but an `IEnumerable<TResult>` where TResult is of type `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`.

```cs
Expression<Func<ProcessRevision, DateTime>> orderProcessRevision = f => f.CreatedAt;
Expression<Func<ProcessRevision, long>> groupProcessRevision = f => f.IdProcess;
// Fix the type and update the lambda to select the first item in the group
Expression<Func<IGrouping<long, ProcessRevision>, ProcessRevision>> selectProcessRevision = f => f.First();

processRevisions = await processRevisionRepository.GetDatasByLastRevisionAsync(orderProcessRevision, groupProcessRevision, selectProcessRevision);

public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetDatasByLastRevisionAsync(
   Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> order,
   Expression<Func<T, long>> group,
   Expression<Func<IGrouping<long, T>, T>> select)
{
   IQueryable<T> query = dbContext.Set<T>();

   query = query.OrderByDescending(order);
   // Don't reassign, create a new var
   var grouped = query.GroupBy(group);
   var selected = grouped.Select(select);

   return await selected.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I received this error on First():
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (p.IdProcess), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: ProcessRevision
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)
    .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().`

Comment: Does it work, if you change `query.GroupBy(group);` to `query.GroupBy(group).ToList();` (or to ToListAsync)? It's not optimal, because you loose the translation to sql, but I'm not aware of any solution which are linq-to-sql compatible...